# Objective-C Extract index of a range returned by rangeOfString:

Tags: objective-c, indexing, nsrange

How to extract an `NSUInteger index` from

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString: substring]
```

so I can write this index in `[array objectAtIndex:index]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// make sure that the substring was actually found:
NSRange result = [string rangeOfString:substring];

if (result.location != NSNotFound)
{
    // make sure that the index exists in the array
    if (result.location < [array count])
    {
        id someObj = [array objectAtIndex:result.location];
        // do something cool with someObj here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:substring];
NSUInteger index = range.location;
//...
```

Comment: range.location returns a really big number if that substring is found in the way beginning of that string. Why is this?

Comment: @coolcool1994 did you find the reason ? I'm having the same problem